# HTML <a download="name"></a> not naming the file properly

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm trying to get the digital versions of some old comic books I already own and found a nice website.
In my interest in coding, I want to make the downloading automatically.
Right now I'm running into the problem that when I try to make a link like this

```
<a href="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/YHE_hS6SdyWOg5Da41rkEiRLE5pnTTIIBuq5Pg7QMkv7TLcVN9uoV4i7Qk-TqojucZf70wJ2EH-Y=s0" download="name.jpg">text</a>
```

on this website https://2.bp.blogspot.com/YHE_hS6SdyWOg5Da41rkEiRLE5pnTTIIBuq5Pg7QMkv7TLcVN9uoV4i7Qk-TqojucZf70wJ2EH-Y=s0, when I click the link it doesn't name the file name.jpg but instead RCO001_1466087147.jpg

This way of downloading and naming the file works for me on other websites but not on this one.
I'm using firefox and an `mouse.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)` to automate the clicking/downloading. It also doesn't work when clicked manually.

If you know another way to download images through the browser console which allows me to name the files OR choose where they're downloaded then that would also be sufficient

A friend of mine already gave me a solution that befits me.

Solution: Since I already know the URLs that I want I can run the download through node.js and use the build-in filesystem (fs) instead of these weird links

Comment: What are you using to automate the downloads? Is it an extension, or something else controlling firefox?

Comment: I'm using my own written js code, that runs on https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Star-Wars-Starfighter-Crossbones/Issue-1?id=174930 for example and extracts all image URLs which I then use on the image website(because of cross-site downloading restrictions)  where another own written js code function is that creates links with those URLs, clicks them and then deletes the link

Comment: The response to the URL you are requesting there, contains the header `content-disposition: inline;filename="RCO001_1466087147.jpg"` – so the filename `RCO001_1466087147.jpg` gets specified by that. You can not overwrite this with a `download` attribute on the link. If the server already suggested a file name in the response, then this takes priority over whatever you might suggest via the `download` attribute.

Comment: and there is no workaround for that?